How to fix ran out of memory issue on solana network
I am facing below issue, but actually I am not sure what the reason is.
Could you please take a look at this issue and let me know how to fix this?
https://solana.fm/tx/2Z8LBFUuPifZCjvBkCxAvcg893J7dMDXjjv37utKihNT2aDaszoib7BqMAvQoS55hewQfUkj3xjU3C8HnRDZrT8b?cluster=mainnet-alpha

